# How to apply a theme / style in android without restarting the activity?

Tags: android

I have an application where the user can chose between several different colored themes from a `PreferenceActivity` and thereby change the theme / color of the entire application. But the changes selected in the `PreferenceActivity` do not apply immediately. The changes are applied only when the user **reenters** the `PreferenceActivity`.

I know I can call `recreate()` every time a theme is chosen, but I want to know if a better solution exists without recreating the entire activity.

**Here is an video of how it currently works:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oU8xIUi_48A

**This is where I set the chosen value from the preferenceList in my PreferenceActivity:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme();
    themecolorList.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            switch (themecolorList.getValue()) {

                case "grey":
                    themecolorList.getEditor().putString("grey", "green").apply();
                    break;
                case "green":
                    themecolorList.getEditor().putString("green", "green").apply();
                    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_default);
                    break;
                case "blue":
                    themecolorList.getEditor().putString("blue", "green").apply();
                    break;
                case "yellow":
                    themecolorList.getEditor().putString("yellow", "green").apply();
                    break;
                case "red":
                    themecolorList.getEditor().putString("red", "green").apply();
                    break;
                case "pink":
                    themecolorList.getEditor().putString("pink", "green").apply();
                    break;

                default:
                    themecolorList.getEditor().putString("green", "green").apply();
                    break;
            }

            recreate();
            return true;


        }
    });
  }
```

The method `setTheme();` is called in my PreferenceActivitys `onCreate();` method

```
private void setTheme() {

   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    switch (sharedPreferences.getString("THEME_KEY", "green")) {

        case "grey":
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Grey);
            break;

        case "green":
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_default);
            break;

        case "blue":
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Blue);
            break;

        case "yellow":
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Yellow);
            break;

        case "red":
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Red);
            break;

        case "pink":
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Pink);
            break;

        default:
            getApplication().setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_default);
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_default);
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to be that the best solution is to use `recreate()`; since there is no other way to refresh a whole layout for an activity:

For everytime the user presses on a options from the list of themes
the key/value for the pressed one is saved via `OnPreferenceChangeListener`  in a `SharedPreference` and `recreate();` is then called.

```
themecolorList.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            recreate();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

In my `PreferenceActivity`s `onCreate();` I call a custom made method `setTheme();` which is called after `recreate();` is called. The `setTheme();` just looks up what is saved in `SharedPreference` from the `OnPreferenceChangeListener` and set the theme to corresponding value

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Comment: the recreate() make all activity recreated

Answer (score 0):

You can't.
You can start a new activity for selecting theme and when user selects finish that activity.

Comment: Using `recreate();` will be a better option then, than starting a new intent for everytime the user presses on an option in the preferencelist

Answer (score 0):

Triggering a layout update (by rotating the device, or making the app think it's rotated) should normally cause it to reload its resources.

I don't remember exactly how to do it at the moment, but it was a common practice the last time I investigated how to do something similar. 
Just remember to specify (in the manifest?) that your activity will handle layout changes/screen rotation to avoid a full restart (and loss of any unsaved data).

Comment: Sounds as a cool solution. The only catch is that I have made my App to only work in potrait mode, since using it in landscape mode is unpractical.

Comment: Haha, I had the exact same problem as you then! :p (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705963/forcing-a-different-locale-works-only-for-top-activity-in-back-stack/11710007#comment15537029_11710007).
But then I think you're stuck with recreating the activity, alternatively you could make a preview (image popup, or apply style colours to the list item, if possible?) and then just recreate the activity (using a Bundle to supply the current state to the new instance if needed) when the user makes a selection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. It works for me.

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class App : Application(){

    companion object{
       private var isOpening = true
        fun appIsOpening(sync : (Boolean) -> Unit){
            sync(isOpening)
            isOpening = false
        }
    }

}
```

and

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class SingleActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        installSplashScreen()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        App.appIsOpening { it ->
            if (it)setStartDestination()
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like there is a method called `invalidate()` to be called on views that need to be redrawn.

[Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate())

Which should allow you to call on individual views that only need redrawing. Not the whole activity.

Comment: In a `PreferenceActivity` or `AppCompatPreferenceActivity` there is only these: `invalidateOptionsMenu();` `invalidateHeaders();`and neither of these works