# Android change Locale on One Activity Only

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, localization

I have Just one Activity that i need it with a different locale.
Example my Default App Local is English and i want to Open an Activity where it content is Arabic. 
how can i force this activity to read from the values-ar ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985805/set-locale-programatically

Comment: I just want a specific locale for one Activity, not the whole application

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705963/forcing-a-different-locale-works-only-for-top-activity-in-back-stack

Answer (score 0):

update the locale by using the below code and change the locale to your preferred one and restart the activity

```
 Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
    config.locale = Globals.locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration( config, null );
    Intent restart = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity( restart );
```

Comment: Edit your answer with explanation. It was flagged as low quality post